# My rtl8811au usb adapter seems to not work properly

Tags: wireless

I bought the rtl8811au usb wifi adapter for my workstation. Installing the driver that come with the usb adapter fails on linux so I installed that driver:

`https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git`

and it works.
But I noticed that some time, or frequently, it seems to go to sleep for a while and then it works again. And another issue is that ti seems to not work with some javascript, in fact in some web page, it cannot load the javascript controls.

So, how can I fix that behavior ? It depends on driver version I installed ?

EDIT: I ran wireless-info script and [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JjgqnFX5Cd/) there is my log:

Comment: Start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: You can find the right answer on this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056291/driver-rtl8811au-for-usb-wifi/1056293#1056293)