# Driver rtl8811au for usb wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, realtek, realtek-wireless

I bought a rtl8811au chipest based usb wifi for my work stationd that supports dual band. But when I plugged in the usb my ubuntu doesn't recognized it. So I had to find the driver and compiled it 'cause the one inside the usb package was not compatible with the last kernel version.

My experience with some drivers get from github platform was unsatisfied.

All the drivers I tested are an issue in my user experience. It seems that, with these drivers, my wifi usb stops working randomly, specially when the browser is open and it loads some javascript.

In that context the ping command works normally and all the other connections such as p2p like torrent, or app like telegram.

When that issue shows up, I have some options:

- Waiting to work again with do nothing
- Unplug and replug the usb dongle
- Restart network service or turn off and turn on wifi

With all these options I have to wait and it is so heartbreaking !

So I think that the problem is relative to the driver 'cause I get it from github and it can contain some error.

I tried drivers like:

- https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU
- https://github.com/sloretz/rtl8811au
- https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git

and the problem still persists on all these drivers.

Do you know some driver that works properly ?

Comment: What is the result from terminal for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: for reference: also check kali deb: https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms# https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/contrib/r/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms/realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms_5.3.4~20200115-0kali1_all.deb

Answer (score 14):

For Kernel version 5 and above use this [repo](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)

Follow the instructions in the readme it's really easy!

To sum things up:

```
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
cd ./rtl8812au
make
```

Check if the driver compiled properly and works:

```
sudo insmod 8812au.ko
```

Install:

```
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo depmod
```

Comment: This version of the driver for the 8811au chipset is better than others in my opinion , and you can install it by using dkms for an automatic reinstall at every kernel upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for NETIS WF2180 and 5.3.0-28 kernel on Ubuntu 18.04.3. Have compiled it instead of rtl8812au-dkms package which has stop work on 5.3.0-26... Try 'sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms; sudo rmmod 8812au.ko' in this case before compile from source.

Comment: hmm, the git clone for this just keeps asking for authentication, not sure why

Comment: Interesting, maybe he made it private

Comment: Yup, 404 on that repo now :-(

Comment: Seems like there is a copy here: https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au Updating my answer with the new link

Comment: @yurikleb Your new link and procedure worked for me under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I'd also like to add that the USB ID (via lsusb) for my device is 0dba:0811.

Answer (score 10):

Looking arch wiki they mentioned the chipset `rtl8811au` and they suggest a packet for its drivers.

```
sudo apt install dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au.git
cd ./rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

So fallowing these command you can install the full working driver and get your rtl8811au wifi dongle works without issues !

Comment: EDUP usb dongle began working immediately. light started blinking without reboot or logout. rtl8812au (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01CCMUN8C)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install the driver from official Ubuntu repos by:

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Comment: I remember that I tried it, but if I come here I think that it does not work properly

Comment: It is the same driver. Maybe it didn't build on some distro/kernel combination, but this is the conventional way that works in most cases. You didn't give information regarding your system, so...

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.15.0-24

Comment: Just tried it, it's not the correct driver for my hardware: 
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0xb812 
  bcdDevice            2.10
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
  iSerial                 3 123456`

Answer (score 0):

Had some troubles installing Comfast CF-915AC rtl8811au driver on Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie).

Got below steps working in the end:

```
wget https://pishop.nz/static/downloads/install-wifi2.sh

chmod +x install-wifi2.sh

./install-wifi2.sh

sudo reboot
```

Note: It's getting the drivers from http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/ depend on your "kernel" and "build" and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My wifi adapter is rtl8811au.

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Resume:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
$ cd rtl*
$ sudo make dkms_install
```

Then, reconnect your usb wifi adapter and you can view your wifi selector in the network corner config and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The official Kali/Alfa driver is placed here:

https://github.com/morrownr/8814au