# RTL8811AU + RNX G300EX WiFi adapter driver issues with a twist

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb, hp, realtek-wireless

I've been lurking for some answers about the RTL8811AU EDUP and Rosewill G300EX WiFi adapter. The Rosewill adapter that I dug out of my basement picks up wifi signals, tries to connect, and then drops them for no reason I can decipher.

The USB adapter, on the other hand, doesn't even turn on. I do have a USB hub because I thought it was a power issue, but that didn't work. There's a twist; I have no internet access on that computer (The adapters aren't working!) so I can't install any packages. I've even tried USB tethering with an iPhone. I do not have access to wired internet.

My PC is an HP XW4600 running Ubuntu 18.06. I am willing to run some diagnostics if you have any questions, but it is limited- I can't even run ifconfig, because I need to install packages over the internet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can download packages on any other PC, then here's a solution, as described in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056291/driver-rtl8811au-for-usb-wifi/1056293#1056293) to install RTL8811AU driver:

```
sudo apt install dkms
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8812au.git
```

now copy that directory over onto the machine that does not have Internet access and execute there:

```
cd ./rtl8812au
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Though, in addition to cloning git as mentioned above, you would need [DKMS for Ubuntu 18.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dkms), and its dependencies too so have a [look here on how to install packages off-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: I am not able to install packages. I am going out today to buy a wired ethernet cable, so hopefully that works.

Comment: **@GeorgeVokac** See [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1164478/revisions) but an Ethernet cable would be the easiest solution to your problem though...  **Jags**: An edit *and an upvote!* **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby thanks alot, and @ George Vokac for any reason, if ethernet solution is not working for you, please let us know.