# RTL8811AU install on 19.10 fails

Tags: wireless, git, realtek-wireless, ubuntu-drivers, netgear

I recently purchased Netgear AC600 dual band (USB ID-0846-9052, RTL8811AU) and tried installing wireless driver on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine. Almost most of the threads in GitHub are based on rtl8812au even though I tried the following steps.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au
sudo dkms build rtl8812au/4.2.2
sudo dkms install rtl8812au/4.2.2
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

I've been trying the wrong version, and haven't found the current version yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driver rtl8811au for usb wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056291/driver-rtl8811au-for-usb-wifi)

Comment: I did . "sudo ./dkms-install.sh " command not found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need rtl8814au driver for kernel 5.3 on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185952/need-rtl8814au-driver-for-kernel-5-3-on-ubuntu-19-10)

Comment: If you are sure that your chipset is of rtl8811au then try the 1st one or else if its 8812au then try 2nd. 1) https://github.com/sloretz/rtl8811au  2) https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au